Re-sampling 2d DEM data into a regular local-level array
I need to compute a number of geometric ranges from arbitrary points to surface heights in HAE from a digital elevation model (DEM). This surface height data is provided in WGS84 Lat/Long/MSL elevation, which I can adjust into HAE from a geoid model and store prior to program execution. I can translate the required DEM data for the needed area around the reference point into an array of local-level points (East/North/Up is what I'm using here).
The reference points data is provided in a local-level reference based on a specific ENU origin point in Lat/Long/Height which I don't know until runtime. The most significant compute task is an iteration of various distance computations between (E,N,U) reference points in the local-level frame and up to ~100,000 sampled points in the surface reference contour. Not a big problem for NumPy.
The DEM data translated into the ENU frame is not regular in East/North alignment. The algorithm I'm implementing requires me to return ranges to regularly spaced East/North points and return computations specific to a raster of East/North surface points. My ENU-space DEM object is a ~6000x7000x3 ndarray with the relevant search area surface locations. Viewed in East/North it's warped a bit like a trapezoid that's wider and slightly bowed in the direction of the equator as a result of the transformation.
The best I've been able to do is:
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator
# Fake DEM data (don't know how to warp it in the way the TED output is, so just adding some rand) This
# could use a rectilinear interpolator, but I believe my data cannot (warped in E as a function of N and
# vice versa).
e_dim = 7000
n_dim = 6000
e_rng = np.arange(-e_dim/2, e_dim/2, dtype='float32')*72 + np.random.randint(-100, high=101, size=e_dim)
n_rng = np.arange(-n_dim/2, n_dim/2, dtype='float32')*95 + np.random.randint(-100, high=101, size=n_dim)
dem_u = np.random.randint(-100, high=4500, size=(n_dim,e_dim))
row, col = np.meshgrid(n_rng, e_rng, indexing='ij')
ENU = np.dstack((row,col,dem_u))

# looking for a faster approach to lookup Nx2 arrays of E/N points that are on a regular sample grid for # rastered final output

interp = NearestNDInterpolator(
        (ENU[:,:,0].flatten(),ENU[:,:,1].flatten()),
         ENU[:,:,2].flatten())
# times about 12-13s on my hardware--pretty darn slow.
interval_m = 11338.7 # Just a coarse starting sample dimension
samp_offsets_m = np.array([-150*1852+i*interval_m for i in
                               range(pts_side) ] )
tiles_x, tiles_y = np.meshgrid(samp_offsets_m, samp_offsets_m, indexing='xy' )
pTL = np.asarray( [[*tiles_x.flatten()],    E pos
                   [*tiles_y.flatten()]])   N pos

interp(pTL[0], pTL[1])   # pretty fast, about 4ms to update 'Up' on ~2500 samples.

Is there a better way to create a regularly aligned structure to do DEM lookups into in the local-level plane? My target environment can't run GDAL/Rasterio, etc. I can prep the DEM set with those tools but it isn't in the runtime environment.

Do you have the option to pre build the DEM model and load it as file or will it change to often ?

The larger data structure the DEM comes from is HAE referenced to Lat/Lon/HAE (and is pre-cached to a file, accessed as memmap and the search range plus a buffer around the runtime reference location is loaded to memory and transformed to ENU).  You're correct in thinking it will not change often, but doing many range computations is seemed most efficient in a cartesian system like ENU or ECEF, and the sampling scheme (breaking up the local East/North level plane) is most straightforward in ENU.

So we may consider saving the ENU and reload it when needed?

Yes--I see this reference as only changing when the search area position changes significantly (probably no more than 5-10 minutes apart, likely in the case of a poor starting estimate).

Provided your procedure is correct for the task you are performing and we want to keep it, there is few improvement to do.
As you noticed, building the interpolator is time consuming:
%timeit -n 1 -r 30 interp = NearestNDInterpolator((ENU[:,:,0].flatten(), ENU[:,:,1].flatten()), ENU[:,:,2].flatten())
# 11.8 s ± 488 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 30 runs, 1 loop each)

And takes almost the same amount of time on my machine, they should be comparable.
First, you can use ravel instead of flatten that will avoid a copy of your arrays and spare a bit of memory.
%timeit -n 1 -r 30 interp = NearestNDInterpolator((ENU[:,:,0].ravel(), ENU[:,:,1].ravel()), ENU[:,:,2].ravel())
# 11.7 s ± 630 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 30 runs, 1 loop each)

But it does not makes any time improvement, it's just about memory.
Now we must consider the fact that most of the time spent by this step is building the underlying KD-Tree. Fortunately, NearestNDInterpolator gives you the opportunity to setup how this cKDTree must be built.
%timeit -n 1 -r 30 interp = NearestNDInterpolator((ENU[:,:,0].ravel(), ENU[:,:,1].ravel()), ENU[:,:,2].ravel(), tree_options={"compact_nodes": False, "balanced_tree": False, "leafsize": 64})
# 3.67 s ± 254 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 30 runs, 1 loop each)

Making a coarser tree greatly reduces the building time, but may increase the prediction time.
If we compare, prediction time (with pt_side=2500):
%timeit -n 1 -r 30 interp(pTL[0], pTL[1])
# Default tree: 4.36 s ± 149 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 30 runs, 1 loop each)
# Tweaked tree: 5.47 s ± 139 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 30 runs, 1 loop each)

Coarser tree requires about 1s more to predict, but needs 8 seconds less to build.
11.7 - 3.67 = 8.03
(11.7 + 4.36) / (3.67 + 5.47) = 1.757111597374179
(11.7 + 4.36) - (3.67 + 5.47) = 6.919999999999998

This is not a 10 or 100 factor optimization, but keeping your procedure as is it's possible to reduce the execution time for a factor of about 1.75 (sparing about 7s by run) by tweaking the tree configuration.

This is a significant speed up, likely good enough for my case. I'm implementing and testing--will report back.

@jlandercy--thanks!  This is a meaningful speedup in build time (12 sec to 3.5 sec) and the back-end lookups using the function ranged from 12% slower at 10k items to 4% faster (!) at 131k items. This was surprising.  Reducing the front-end build time to 3.5 sec is significant in my application. Additionally, I didn't detect any estimation differences between the two interpolator builds to within float32 precision.
